# How to align header in the center of the container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

In stackoverflow page, shown in the image below, you can see that the the body of the page is wrapped in a container and the header is outside that container and stretches but the content inside the header is centered align with the body content. So if the body content width changes so does that content inside the header.

I am trying to accomplish the same thing using MUI. I have a header and a body. The body is wrapped in a container and the header is outside the container. But the content of the header doesn't align with the body when the body width changes based off different screen sizes. This is shown in the second image below. I can use `padding` but with padding it won't adjust to align to the container if the screen size changes. I can also wrap the header inside the container which then will align correctly but then the black background of the header won't stretch to the size of the screen.

Not sure how to proceed?

[Stackoverflow Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92hVA.png)

[My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch9bK.png)

```
import Container from '@mui/material/Container'
import Header from './pages/Header'
import './styles/app.scss'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="change-background-color">
      <Header /> // this uses MUI app-bar
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Body/>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D But I already included my code

Comment: Not all of your code... We don't know what the code in your `Header` component looks like or your css. Creating a codesandbox is really helpful when asking for advice.

Comment: @toadv1ne It's just app header from MUI with a black theme.